# SQL Right Join issue

Tags: sql, oracle

My query make a Right Join, but the results is not correct.
`Null` values must be where column `NAME_2` is equal with `A` and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is the query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd45b/1

For the future readers. The definition of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE S1 (TIME_1 DateTIME, INTERVAL_1 INT, NAME_1 varchar(20),INITIAL_VAL int);
CREATE TABLE S2 (TIME_2 DateTIME, INTERVAL_2 INT, NAME_2 varchar(20), FINAL_VAL int);
```

The data inserts related to the question:

```
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 00:00',1, 'B',13);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 01:00',2, 'B',14);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 02:00',3, 'B',10);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 03:00',4, 'B',15);

INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 00:00',1, 'C',42);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 01:00',2, 'C',10);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 02:00',3, 'C',22);
INSERT INTO S1 values('10.02.2017 03:00',4, 'C',18);


INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 00:00',1, 'A',12);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 01:00',2, 'A',13);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 02:00',3, 'A',9);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 03:00',4, 'A',16);

INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 00:00',1, 'B',16);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 01:00',2, 'B',22);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 02:00',3, 'B',20);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 03:00',4, 'B',10);

INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 00:00',1, 'C',42);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 01:00',2, 'C',15);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 02:00',3, 'C',22);
INSERT INTO S2 values('10.02.2017 03:00',4, 'C',19);
```

Initial query from the question:

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_1) AS V1, * FROM S1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_2) AS V2,* FROM S2
)
SELECT
CTE2.NAME_2,
CTE2.TIME_2,
INTERVAL_2,
CTE1.INITIAL_VAL,
CTE2.FINAL_VAL
FROM CTE1
RIGHT JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.V1=CTE2.V2
```

Comment: Show us the query as formatted test as well. Also consider a switch to left join instead. Most people find right join utterly confusing. (`main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: I think you are confusing here. You thought that you join with `CTE1.name_1=CTE2.name_2;` so `name_2 = 'A'` will have NULL value when join with cte1. But here you use `CTE1.V1=CTE2.V2;` which is `ROW_NUMBER() order by name_x`, not `name_x` itself.

Comment: Your fiddle is on sql server 2014, while you tagged your question with Oracle. What rdbms are you using?

Comment: @Pham X if I put `CTE1.name_1=CTE2.name_2` the results is a Cartesian Product

Comment: @ZoharPeled I use Oracle

Comment: Then you must understanding your intention first. What do you want (logic)? And for that logic, what is your expected result ?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach The result must be with `Null` for the first 4 rows from `INITIAL_VAL` column instead for the last 4 rows.

Comment: Do you have any logic for that expected result? If you only want 4 first rows to be null, it's very easy but may not the logic you want so it may be wrong in other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right join is matching over `ROW_NUMBER` produced. So it doesn't matter that it's `NAME_2` value: `A`, doesn't have a match with NAME_1 value.

It is matching `A` from table `S1` with `B` from table`S2`, because they both get the same `ROW_NUMBER`

Please run this to see what is matched when you do right join:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_1) AS V1, * FROM S1;
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_2) AS V2,* FROM S2;
```

Edit:
Answering to your question from the comment. It is very hard to know what exactly do you need to build, but I think that the interval might bring some interesting results:

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_1) AS V1, * FROM S1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_2) AS V2,* FROM S2
)
SELECT
CTE2.NAME_2,
CTE2.TIME_2,
INTERVAL_2,
CTE1.INITIAL_VAL,
CTE2.FINAL_VAL
FROM CTE1
RIGHT JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.NAME_1=CTE2.NAME_2 AND CTE1.INTERVAL_1 = CTE2.INTERVAL_2
```

Comment: You are right, but how can I fix this? I need something like that: `ON CTE1.NAME_1.NAME_1=CTE2.NAME_2.NAME_2`

Answer (score 0):

Is the interval always Same for Name_1 and Name_2?. Otherwise it will go wrong again. Not sure whether you need a join only on Name column or combination of Name & interval. Please ignore if answer given by Jakub Szumiato is already working for you. I have taken a simple test data and executed with the Query given by Jakub Szumiato. This is the output.

[image]

Comment: `Interval` is from hour interval so, for `00:00`  the interval is `1` for `01:00` interval is `2` and so on...